# Windows - MAC address whitelist on wired network?

Tags: windows, networking, firewall, mac-address

In Windows (XP or 7), is it possible to configure either Windows, a software firewall, or network cards such that the computer will only communicate with specific known MAC addresses (e.g. the MAC address of a particular router)?

Comment: This would depend on the networking equipment you have.

Comment: I imagine that yes, this could be done with a software firewall, which software firewalls do this, I dunno...

Comment: @Ramhound: OK, then assume that our networking equipment is: ... The ethernet port on a Dell workstation's motherboard.

Comment: @OJW - More concered with the router/switch networking equipment.  You won't be able to do this on the machine itself.

Comment: Why not?  Machines can have firewalls.  Firewalls can see MAC addresses.